# Font Awesome fonts not loading in Angular afte ng build

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome, ng-build

I am using Angular 8. I have added the font-awesome path in the angular.json like this.

```
"./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
```

However, all the icons were coming as empty boxes (not loading). So, I put all the font-awesome files in the assets folder. Then, I put a link to the css file in the index.html

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/css/font-awesome.css">
```

It still did not work. So, I hit the font-awesome.css file directly from my browser.

```
mysite.mymy/assets/styles/css/font-awesome.css
```

It did open up in the browser. The css file has a link to "../fonts/". Like below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

So, I hit that link.

```
mysite.mymy/assets/styles/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0
```

But it is redirecting to the home page. What's the issue? Icons are not loading.

Comment: Do u use ng build --prod ? And when it is in node modules when u check  emty boxes in developer console do u see any fontawesome  css there?

Comment: Only ng build. Yes, font-awesome css are coming when i inspect the empty boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Angular 2.0 final release, the structure of the Angular2 CLI project has been changed — you don't need any vendor files, no system.js — only webpack. So you do:

1. `npm install font-awesome --save`
2. In the `angular-cli.json` file locate the `styles[]` array and add font-awesome references directory here, like below:

---

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      ....
      "styles": [
          "styles.css",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" // -here ebpack will 
   automatically build a link css element out of this!?
      ],
      ...
  }
  ]
],
```

> In more recent versions of Angular, use the `angular.json` file
>   instead, without the `../`. For example, use
>   `"node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"`

3. Place some font-awesome icons in any html file you want:
4. Stop the application <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> then re-run the app using `ng serve` because the watchers are only for the src folder and `angular-cli.json` is not observed for changes.
5. Enjoy your awesome icons!

Comment: I have put it in the angular.json as well. I copied it to the assets specifically because it was not working